# Explain nested list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need an insight into understanding the below code. The first print gives me output: 'a' whereas on changing the value of `y[0][0]` to "p" it changes the value of `y[0][0]`, `y[1][0]`, `y[2][0]` and `y[3][0]` as well. I was expecting an output like `[['p', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]` but instead got `[['p', 'b', 'c'], ['p', 'b', 'c'], ['p', 'b', 'c'], ['p', 'b', 'c']]`

```
x=["a","b","c"]
y = [x] * 4
# first print
print(y[0][0])

y[0][0] = "p"
# second print
print(y)
```

Comment: Try doing `y = [list("abc"), list("abc"), list("abc"), list("abc")]`. I dont know if there is a better pythonic way to write this.

Comment: `y=[x.copy() for i in range(4)]` use this. then you will able t0 change individual vlaues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `*` operator is not exact, it's kind of funny, so use `range`.

It will work by replacing the below line:

```
y = [x] * 4
```

With:

```
y = [x.copy() for i in range(4)]
```

Use `copy` which creates a copy of something else, and actually `copy` is creating a same thing when `print`ing it, but different `id`, different object really, so your code won't do the above reproduction again.

Also, you've got your question closed as a duplicate of:

*[List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)*

Which have much better explanations.

Comment: `y = [x for i in range(4)]`  creates the reference to the same list. If you do a `id(y[0])` and `id(y[1])`, it returns same number. I didn't downvote, if that helps.

Comment: Both of your lines of code have the same effect. Also, "it's kind of funny" is not a helpful statement.

Comment: it's creating a shallow copy(all element reference to same memory loc)

Comment: @shahkalpesh Edited mine

Comment: @RichardMöhn Edited mine.

Comment: @prashantrana Edited mine.

Comment: Thanks for all of you telling me why the donw-vote

Comment: @U9-Forward Dude, also explain deep copy and shallow copy . It will be helpful to others.

Comment: @prashantrana Okay will edit.

Comment: @prashantrana Finshed my edit.

Comment: It's still hard to understand. And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly has much better answers, so why bother?

Comment: @RichardMöhn How about referring to the link?

Comment: Don't answer obvious duplicates. It fragments information and dilutes the quality of content on site.

Comment: @wim I won't do next time.\

Comment: @U9-Forward. Thanks for the link. That helped with the explanation.